# How do I use File.join with File::ALT_SEPARATOR?

Tags: ruby, rake-task, albacore

I want to use `File.join()` for building paths in Ruby:

```
File.Join("Dir1", "Dir2", "Dir3")
```

Result is:

```
Dir1/Dir2/Dir3
```

I want `File.join()` to uses File::ALT_SEPARATOR for doing this:

```
Dir1\Dir2\Dir3
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want it to use reverse slashes? Ruby, and by extension, Rake, doesn't require them. "Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb". When specifying a Windows-style filename in a Ruby string, remember to escape the backslashes: `"c:\\gumby\\ruby\\test.rb"`"

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at Ruby's built-in [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
File.join('Dir1','Dir2').gsub(File::SEPARATOR,
     File::ALT_SEPARATOR || File::SEPARATOR)
```

Comment: I guess it's implied that File::ALT_SEPARATOR can be nil on some platforms... I wonder which?

Comment: For some very weird reason, I had to start using this on my Win10 box against paths as args in command-line. Not sure what I updated that broke it...

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean on linux (at least CentOS)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this function to `File`:

```rb
def File.join_alt(*fnames)
  sep = File::ALT_SEPARATOR || File::SEPARATOR
  fnames.map(&:to_s) # Anything with to_s
    .join(sep)       # Work on all platforms
end
```